# How does the Pocket reader feature works in Firefox 38.0.5?

Tags: firefox

The feature is only working with some websites for me, what i wanted to know is how does it work?

Are these websites specifically supported? Or is it that this feature just "knows" what you want to read?

Comment: How does it show to you that it doesn not work for a page? Have you an example which page doesn't work so one could test?

Comment: It doesn't work with forums and online communities, like reddit.com for example.